# What's the correct password for Fallout: New Vegas first computer hack?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

Further detailing the question, what's the correct password for the terminal inside the Schoolhouse in Goodsprings?

Comment: IIRC the passwords are *not* unique or fixed, but are selected randomly. Instead you'll need to learn how the minigame works and how to beat it. [This](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17461/can-we-really-hack-each-pc-we-come-across-in-fallout-3) question is related and might provide some insights.

Comment: @DMA, you should put that as an answer.

Comment: @Dave, good point, done.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The passwords are not unique or fixed, but are selected randomly, so the password is different for each player (and even each time you visit it).

Instead, you'll need to learn how the minigame works, and how to beat it.

The "quick" description of play is:
Select any password on the screen, you will be then told how many letters it matchs to the correct password (eg, `3/7` means the word selected has 3 identical letters in exactly the same place as the correct password). Using that information find other possible words that match that criteria and give them a try.

[This](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17461/can-we-really-hack-each-pc-we-come-across-in-fallout-3) question is related and might provide some deeper insights.

Comment: There are other things that just the words that are clickable. Other clickable areas will remove duds or reset your number of tries.

Comment: @Amazed true, but the linked question covers those quite well already, so I didn't bother to duplicate.